# Doxygen : How to add ref to a folder file reference?

Tags: indexing, reference, directory, doxygen, ref

I'd like to make a reference in my documentation to the source folder reference in Doxygen. These pages are already available in the index (the src folder file list, and one for each subfolder).

I've tried `\ref` and `\link` commands without any success (the `ref` is not resolved and the `link` aims to the current page).

One another (bad) solution should be to make an html link with the adress of the page (`generatedDocumenation/html/dir_840ce71ebaba6062e222272fd2be405d.html` for example), but I'm afraid this reference could change "randomly" at each generation, and it won't work for any kind of other output.

Do these pages have an implicit name to use for a `ref` command ?

Thanks in advance, 
Babcool